# vlcj media player doesn't play video, no fail message

Tags: java, vlcj

I have done a video player using vlcj library of vlc media player.
When i run the code the frame open fine but the video dosen't play.

Here is my code to do that..

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setLocation(100,100);
    f.setSize(1000,600);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);


    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    c.setBackground(Color.black);
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    p.add(c);
    f.add(p);


    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
    Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);


    MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();

    EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new DefaultFullScreenStrategy(f));
            emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(c));

    //emp.toggleFullScreen();

    emp.setEnableMouseInputHandling(false);
    emp.setEnableKeyInputHandling(false);


    String file= "C:\\!temp\\v.mp4";

    emp.prepareMedia(file);

    }

}
```

This is on my console:

```
nov. 03, 2015 12:04:40 DU uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info <init>
INFO: vlcj: 3.8.0
nov. 03, 2015 12:04:40 DU uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info <init>
INFO: java: 1.8.0_65 Oracle Corporation
nov. 03, 2015 12:04:40 DU uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info <init>
INFO: java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65
nov. 03, 2015 12:04:40 DU uk.co.caprica.vlcj.Info <init>
INFO: os: Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64
nov. 03, 2015 12:04:40 DU uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory create
INFO: vlc: 2.2.1 Terry Pratchett (Weatherwax), changeset 2.2.1-0-ga425c42
nov. 03, 2015 12:04:40 DU uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlcFactory create
INFO: libvlc: C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\libvlc.dll
```

Comment: "!temp" looks strange. Does the file exits?

Answer (score 1):

The `prepareMedia()` method just gets the media 'ready', it does not actually play it.

So use `play()` after you prepare it, or miss prepare out and just use `playMedia(...)` instead.

And as per the other comment, are you sure "!temp" is correct?

Comment: All right! It's working! Thanks for your useful advice!